# Can the default Color Dialog be put into the background/minimised?

Tags: c#, winforms

***This is solved and what I'm asking is impossible due the dialog being modal.**

I would like to know if the default color dialog can be put into the background as trying to click off of it prompts you to close the dialog first.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog();

if (colorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    p.Color = colorDialog.Color;
}
```

The only solution I can think of is to open it as a new process.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is this WinForms?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm creating it in visual studio.

Comment: I believe you want to show the ColorDialog in a "modeless" way (as opposed to displaying it in a "modal" way as you currently are). I'm not sure how to achieve this, although I imagine it must be possible.

Comment: I will google more about this. Thank you.

Comment: It is a _modal_ dialog.  Even if it had a `Modeless` property, the only way to display the window is via `ShowDialog()` which is a blocking call with its own message pump.  There is no `Show()`

Comment: I will take this as what I'm asking is impossible. I've also came to the same conclusion after googling once knowing specifically what to. Thank you John and MickyD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done due to the dialog box being modal.